# Laravel voyager policy based on user role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, user-roles, voyager

I can't find out how to determine user role in voyager. I am trying to do some policy check based on user role like this:

```
public function browse(User $user)
{
  $user->role == 'admin';
}
```

But this returns false (`This action is unauthorized.`) even for user with role admin. 
I am using **laravel 5.6** and **voyager 1.1.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no role or role_name in users table in voyager. I have to use role_id

```
 public function browse(User $user)
    {
     if (  $user->role_id == 1 ) {
     return true;       
     } else {
     return false;      
     }
    }
```

**Is there any way I can use role name?**

Comment: Yeah there is!, You can use: $user->hasRole('admin'); : returns boolean; if this user is admin;